# How do you implement XMLHttpRequest in javascript using ant design Upload component to send to google cloud storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-storage, antd

I am trying to upload to google cloud storage using the XML api. This is an example form that is used to do that. *Thanks Brandon Yarbrough*

```
<form action="http://my-bucket.storage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="key" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="sample_token=">
   <input name="file" type="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I am also using ant design Upload component to do that.

> https://ant.design/components/upload/

The documents indicate to use the 'customRequest' prop to have the ability to implement your own XMLHttpRequest. Furthermore it links to some more documentation that describes the object that 'customRequest' receives, which I've destructured below as an argument.

> https://github.com/react-component/upload#customrequest

I've attempted to implement.

```
render() {
  const props = {
    name: 'file',
    action: '//localhost:3000/my-express-endpoint',
    data: {
      'key': 'value'
    },
    customRequest({ onProgress, onError, onSuccess, data, filename, file, withCredentials, action, headers }) {
      let data = new FormData();   // Using FormData counting on browser support.
      data.append('signature', 'sample_token');

      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'http://my-bucket.storage.googleapis.com', true);
      xhr.onload = function () {
        // do something to response
        console.log(this.responseText);
      };
      xhr.send(data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Dragger {...props}>
        ...drop file here
      </Dragger>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am unclear how to execute the customRequest. Since I'm overriding does that make the other props **name, action, data** outside of the **customRequest** prop invalid and now handled inside the customRequest prop since those were the same? Also since I'm uploading directly to google cloud storage using the XML api does that mean I no longer have to take care of it with my-express-endpoint and handling it with for example multer on server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters: The `action` and `data` option properties are not applicable when you provide a `customRequest`. Thus you are correct, you no longer need your express endpoint since your express server is not involved in the transaction.

The more difficult part is handling the file object. When you use an `<input type=file ...>` in  a form (as in your first example) there is a bit of magic going on behind the scenes.

This magic (reading the file, actually) you will have to do yourself when you create the XHR yourself. Recommended reading: The "Dealing with binary data" section two thirds down the page at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

But there are better ways. I would suggest using a xhr wrapper that does the work for you. Such as https://github.com/axios/axios, which can handle the File object you get in customRequest directly.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I thought for some reason XMLHttpRequest was different then using axios. That just made it a lot easier.